# Multipart file field is unreadable

Tags: go, twitter, multipartform-data, multipart, form-fields

I am trying to upload photos to Twitter. I created a multipart writer and creating a file field using that named media but when I send my request to Twitter it keeps responding missing media field.
Am I missing something? 
Here is my code

```
    f, err := os.Open("/Users/nikos/Desktop/test.png")
errored:
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    var img = new(bytes.Buffer)
    enc := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, img)
    _, err = io.Copy(enc, f)
    if nil != err {
        goto errored
    }
    body := new(bytes.Buffer)//Multipart body
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    cl, err := twitter.OauthClient.MakeHttpClient(&oauth.AccessToken{
        Token:  "xxx",
        Secret: "yyy",
    })
    err = writer.WriteField("media_data", img.String())//base64 version of the image (i tried both binary and base64 versions neither will work)
    if nil != err {
        goto errored
    }
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("media", "test.png")//actual binary file multiparted and it is named media.
    if nil != err {
        goto errored
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(part, f)
    if nil != err {
        goto errored
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST",
        "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json",
        body)
    if nil != err {
        goto errored
    }
    res, err := cl.Do(req)
    if nil != err {
        goto errored
    }
//and twitter responds that there is no field attached named media
    _, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, res.Body)
    fmt.Println(res)
    if nil != err {
        goto errored
    }
```

Comment: what's the error that you're seeing ?

Comment: @CeriseLimón i sent one at a time just here  i wrote them together but ill try to close the writer and if i set the content type i get a bad request error let me try closing the writer

Comment: @YandryPozo `{"errors":[{"code":38,"message":"media parameter is missing."}]}&{400 Bad Request 400` this is the error i get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates: Just referred [Twitter API Upload parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload#Parameters). As per your code snippet you're using both fields `media` and `media_data`. You have to use only one -

- Upload using base64 -> field name is `media_data`
- Upload using raw -> field name is `media`

And, you have to add `Content-Type` header.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST",
    "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json",
    body)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
if err := writer.Close(); err != nil {
   log.Println(err)
}
// Now fire the http request
```

*PS: While composing an answer, in 30 secs gap, @cerise-limón added comment, also close the multipart writer as mentioned by @cerise-limón.*

---

**Asked in the comment:**

> Twitter accepts application/octet-stream, you may not need below approach.

Adding multi-part with user supplied `Content-Type` instead of `application/octet-stream`. Basically you have to do same implementation as convenience wrapper with your content-type.

```
writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
h := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
h.Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"`,
        escapeQuotes(fieldname), escapeQuotes(filename)))
h.Set("Content-Type", "image/png")
part, err := writer.CreatePart(h)
// use part same as before
```

Definition of `escapeQuotes` from multiple-part package.

```
var quoteEscaper = strings.NewReplacer("\\", "\\\\", `"`, "\\\"")
func escapeQuotes(s string) string {
    return quoteEscaper.Replace(s)
}
```

Comment: wow that works like a charm i typed by hand as multipart/form-data before with no success i guess the key vas `writer.FormContentType()`
Thank you.

By any chance might you have any clue about setting the type of the file to image/png instead of application/octet-stream ? @jeevatkm

Comment: Yes, you can. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: i just figured it out from the source code of createFormFile thanks anyway for closing the writer

Comment: I just added it, anyway you know what to do.

Comment: but seems like Twitter still doesn't like it ![](https://ws1.sinaimg.cn/large/006tNc79gy1fgq3tnmyrkj30je05uglo.jpg)
I get this error message anyway

Comment: Updated answer with further info about your code snippet. please have a look.

Comment: so do you have any idea then why twitter complains about the type ? @jeevatkm

Comment: I'm on [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147013/discussion-between-nikoss-and-jeevatkm)